# How do I get rid of all the "Warn this.name might be empty" warnings?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

In my Cat.view.bxb file, I have some UI elements that are based on optional properties in the structure that have warnings attached to them.

WARN this.name might be empty

```
result-view{
  match {
    Cat (this)
  }
  render {
    layout {
      section {
        content {
          paragraph {
            style (Title_XS)
            value ("#{value(this.name)}")

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warnings serve to remind you that the UI elements you've defined will not be displayed if the optional properties are not present.

You should define an `if(exists(this.name))` and define UI elements for when the optional elements are not available.

For example, your code would look something like the following:

```
result-view{
  match {
    Cat (this)
  }
  render {
    layout {
      section {
        content {
          if(exists(this.name)) {
            paragraph {
              style (Title_XS)
              value ("#{value(this.name)}")
            } 
          } else {
            paragraph {
              style (Title_XS)
              value("No name!")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By doing so, you are addressing the root cause of the warning and creating a more responsive output for your users.

Answer (score 0):

if (exists) works and is one way as articulated already and provides excellent context for the user. Another way that may be preferable in certain circumstances is to use the [] square brackets notation - if a section within square brackets renders null then the section is skipped. So for your example:

```
result-view{
  match {
    Cat (this)
  }
  render {
    layout {
      section {
        content {
          paragraph {
            style (Title_XS)
            value ("[#{value(this.name)}]")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```